# Formset + form, zipped to one formset

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's say I want a system where 5 people want to register a service at once, all starting at the same date.

Explicit: 5 name fields (passed with extra=5) and just one date field.

I have tried with BaseFormSet and add_fields, but then I get five date fields too.

An example forms.py:

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()

class DateForm(form.Form):
    date = forms.DateField()
```

An example views.py:

```
NameFormSet = formset_factory(NameForm, extra=5)
#The line under will not work, but illustrates what I want to do. 
NameFormSet.append(DateForm)
if request.method = 'POST':
    formset = NameFormSet(request.POST)
    #Do validation etc.. 
else:
    formset = NameFormSet()
return render_to_response('template.html', { 'formset' : formset })
```

Please help =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just include another DateForm like so?

```
NameFormSet = formset_factory(NameForm, extra=5)

if request.method = 'POST':
    formset = NameFormSet(request.POST)
    date_form = DateForm(request.POST)

    if formset.is_valid() and date_Form.is_valid():
        date = date_form.cleaned_data['date']
        for form in formset:
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            # replace registration with registration model name
            registration = Registration(name=name, date=date)
            registration.save()
        return
else:
    formset = NameFormSet()
    date_form = DateForm()
return render_to_response('template.html', { 'formset' : formset, 'date_form' : date_form })
```